# calculation of the value Pi (π) using recursion in c++

Tags: c++

hey guys i have a little bit confusion regarding my program ....Actually my program is about finding the value of pi using infinite series :-
(4*(1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9-1/11.......so on ))
and i successfully completed my task using recursion ...but i have to do this program by passing only one argument that is n ...and value of n is always an odd number ...by i completed my task using three arguments i.e (n,sum,sign)...is there is any possible way to complete the program with only one argument that is n...sorry for my bad english ....i hope u understand better with the help my code .....here it is :-

```
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;
     float Pie(int n,float sum,float sign){
        if (((n+1)/2)%2==0) //for even terms n sign is -1 and vice versa
            sign=-1.0;
        else
            sign=1.0;
        if (n==1)
            return sum+1;   
        sum=sum+((sign*1.0/n)); 
        return Pie(n-2,sum,sign);
     }
     int main(){
        int n;
        cout<<"enter the value of n : ";//n is always an odd number 
        cin>>n;
        float sum=0.0;
        float sign;
        cout<<"value of pi is "<<4*Pie(n,sum,sign);
     }
```

Comment: One of those arguments is an uninitialized `float` (meaning undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

Create an overload of `Pie` that supplies the initial values:

```
float Pie(int n) { return Pie(n, 0, 0); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an overloaded version of `Pie` that takes a single number and call the recursive version.

Your recursive version is painfully complicated. It can be simplified to:

```
float Pie(int i, int n, float sign){
   if ( i > n )
   {
      return 0;
   }

   return sign*1.0/i + Pie(i+2, n, -sign);
}
```

and the non-recursive version can be:

```
float Pie(int n)
{
   return Pie(1, n, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: The slight disadvantage of this version compared to OP's is that this is not tail-recursive. OP's tail-recursive version can be optimized better.